Using generics to create reusable Widget which can use different Instances of same Bloc
i am completely new to generics and I am struggling to get this running.
I want to create a Reusable Page with a BlocProvider.
I am creating multiple Instances of one Bloc to save code using mixins on the Bloc like this:
mixin ServiceAssistantBloc on Bloc<CustomerAssistantEvent, CustomerAssistantState> {}
mixin EmergencyAssistantBloc on Bloc<CustomerAssistantEvent, CustomerAssistantState> {}
mixin FixAssistantBloc on Bloc<CustomerAssistantEvent, CustomerAssistantState> {}

Two Pages down the Widget Tree there is said Page. Now how can i set up the BlocBuilder for it to know which Bloc has been provided and use it?
I am trying to follow this:
Named BlocProvider to use the same Bloc implementation multiple times in the same widget 
Now if I try to use the BlocBuilder as mentioned above. I get the error that the bloc has not been provided and the app crashes.
class CustomerAssistantChecklist<T extends Bloc<CustomerAssistantEvent, CustomerAssistantState>>  extends StatelessWidget {

  final dynamic selectedCustomer;
  const CustomerAssistantChecklist({super.key, required this.selectedCustomer});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: ListTile(
          title: CustomerFullNameDetails(customer: selectedCustomer),
          subtitle: CustomerAddressDetails(customer: selectedCustomer),
        ),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<T, CustomerAssistantState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          List<Widget> checkListCards = [];
          int index = 0;
          while (index < state.customerTaskList.length) {
            checkListCards.add(checkListCard(state: state, index: index, context: context));
            index++;
          }

          return ListView(
            children: [
              ...checkListCards,
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I provide the Blocs using the mixins like this:

    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ServiceAssistantBloc>(
            create: (context) => CustomerAssistantBloc(
                customerAssistantService:
                    CustomerAssistantService(CustomerAssistantType.service))
              ..add(CustomerChecklistFetched(
                  customerId: selectedServiceClient.id))),
        BlocProvider<EmergencyAssistantBloc>(
            create: (context) => CustomerAssistantBloc(
                customerAssistantService:
                    CustomerAssistantService(CustomerAssistantType.emergency))
              ..add(CustomerChecklistFetched(
                  customerId: selectedServiceClient.id))),
        BlocProvider<FixAssistantBloc>(
            create: (context) => CustomerAssistantBloc(
                customerAssistantService:
                    CustomerAssistantService(CustomerAssistantType.fix))
              ..add(CustomerChecklistFetched(
                  customerId: selectedServiceClient.id))),
      ],
      child: const ServiceClientDetailHomeView(),
    );

and the blocs value is being provided like this while navigating:
                   return MaterialPage<void>(
                      child: BlocProvider.value(
                        value: BlocProvider.of<ServiceAssistantBloc>(context),
                        child: CustomerAssistantChecklist(
                            selectedCustomer:
                                ServiceClientService().selectedCustomer),
                      ),
                    );

